# How to tell tmux when creating a new detached session to issue afterwards another tmux command

Tags: shell, tmux

In my normal shell I create tmux sessions for running in the background with

```
tmux new-session -d -s my-session my-script.sh (1)
```

Now I want to add logging of all output via `pipe-pane` to the session. I know how to do this in a *not*-detached session (when being *inside* tmux):

```
Ctrl-B : pipe-pane -o 'cat >>~/tmp/output.log' (2)
```

But how can I tell tmux *on creation* of a detached session -- via (1) -- to add straight away the `pipe-pane` tmux command?

I basically look for a way in my normal shell to create detached tmux sessions with logging. - I am using tmux 1.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always combine the two commands into one tmux command (I dont have tmux 1.6 to test this on but it works for 2.2):

```
tmux new-session -d -s my-session my-script.sh \; pipe-pane -o 'cat >>~/tmp/output.log'
```

If you were using tmux 2.9 or later you can set a hook to run a command when a new session starts. Put in your ~/.tmux.conf

```
set-hook -g session-created "pipe-pane -o 'cat >>~/tmp/output.log'"
```

To cope with many sessions, you might include the session name in the filename, e.g.  `output.#{session_name}.log`.

Comment: The command concatenation works like a charm. Thanks! The dynamic logfile naming via `output.#{session_name}.log` doesn't seem to be understood by my version 1.6 of tmux.

Comment: You might try the alternative older and simpler abbreviation `#S` instead of  `#{session_name}`. Of course, you don't really need to do this when using the concatenation since you just wrote "-s my-session", so you could just copy the name across, but nonetheless I just tried it with `#S` and that works in 2.2.